# C# SQL query blocks server memory

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm a bit newbie still and I have been assigned with the task of maintaining previosuly done code.
I have a web that simulates SQL Management Studio, limitating deleting options for example, so basic users don't screw our servers.
Well, we have a function that expects a query or queries, it works fine, but our server RAM gets blown up with complex queries, maybe it's not that much data, but its casting xml and all that stuff that I still don't even understand in SQL.

This is the actual function:

```
public DataSet ExecuteMultipleQueries(string queries)
    {
        var results = new DataSet();
        using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            var sqlCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand.Transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = AppSettings.SqlTimeout;
            sqlCommand.CommandText = queries.Trim();
            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = sqlCommand };
            dataAdapter.Fill(results);
            return results;
        }
    }
```

I'm a bit lost, I've read many different answers but either I don't understand them properly or they don't solve my problems in any way.

I know I could use Linq-toSql- or Entity, I tried them but I really don't know how to use them with an "unknown" query, I could try to research more anyway so if you think they will help me approaching a solution, by any means, I will try to learn it.

**So to the point:**

The function seems to stop at `dataAdapter.Fill(results)` when debugging, at that point is where the server tries to answer the query and just consume all its RAM and blocks itself. How can I solve this? I thought maybe by making SQL return a certain amount of data, store it in a certain collection, then continue returning data, and keep going until there is no more data to return from SQL, but I really don't know how to detect if there is any data left to return from SQL.

Also I thought about reading and storing in two different threads, but I don't know how the data that is in one thread can be stored in other thread async (and even less if it solves the issue).

So, yes, I don't have anything clear at all, so any guidance or tip would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: More importantly, why are you executing arbitory SQL statements from the user?  This is stupidly dangerous and **will** result in a 'user' screwing your database.  See the [OWASP - SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) page.

Comment: I agree with BanksySan. This is a terrible idea. If you want to prevent users from doing certain things, then use privileges for that. And if there are users who should not be writing queries, you can create reports for them.

Comment: ...also, wrap you're not disposing of your `Transaction` object.  You need to wrap it in a `using` although, not using it at all might be better.

Comment: The API is limited, so users can't execute DELETEs or DROPs, its an internal website for the QA Team. QA Team can only execute queries from differnet environment, so they can't delete anything

Comment: Also, why is the question being downvoted? I don't mind the downvote, but I would like some type of feedback so I can improve in SO, thanks

Comment: @Mese with a skillfully crafted SQL statement one can do much more damage than just a DELETE or DROP.  The list of what is possibities is quite scarey.  Never, ever, ever trust user supplied data. (I really hope there's nothing important in your database).  It's not enough to just deny DROP or DELETE.

Comment: @BanksySan I understand that properly, but everything is safe and controlled, I just didn't mentioned. Everything is logged, controlled and not everyone has access to this website, only authorized people from the QA Team. Thanks for the advice, next time I'll try to mention this type of things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pagination to fetch only part of the data.

Your code will be like this:

`dataAdapter.Fill(results, 0, pageSize);`

`pageSize` can be at size you want (100 or 250 for example).

You can get more information in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn article.

Comment: That method needs a DataTable and my problem is that I don't know what query or queries the API is going to receive

Comment: In your code you have `DataAdapter` so you can fill it with pages. It's not depend on query.

Comment: So I used your answer and it works, I was confused with the documentation and I still don't know exactly why it works, but it does, i used this `dataAdapter.Fill(results, currentIndex, pageSize, results.DataSetName);` So thankful you guys tried helped me

Answer (score 2):

In order to investigate, try the following:

- Start SQL profiler (it is usually installed along with [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) and can be started from Management Studio, Tools menu)
- Make sure you fill up some filters (either NT username or at least the database you are profiling). This is to catch as specific (i.e. only your) queries as possible
- Include starting events to see when your query starts (e.g. [RPC:Starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175927.aspx)).
- Start your application
- Start the profiler before issuing the query (fill the adapter)
- Issue the query -> you should see the query start in the profiler
- Stop the profiler not to catch other queries (it puts overhead on SQL Server)
- Stop the application (no reason to mess with server until the analysis is done)
- Take the query within SQL Management Studio. I expect a SELECT that returns a lot of data. Do not run as it is, but put a `TOP` to limit its results. E.g. `SELECT TOP 1000 <some columns> from ....`

If the TOPed select runs slowly, you are returning too much data.

This may be due to returning some large fields such as `N/VARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)`. One possible solution is to exclude these fields from the initial SELECT and lazy-load this data (as needed).

Check these steps and come back with your actual query, if needed.

Comment: This didn't help with my problem, BUT it helps me analyzing how the query affects the server's memory and more. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Yes, you should dig into what you are actually querying. The accepted answer reference clearly states: The DataAdapter provides a facility for returning only a page of data, through overloads of the Fill method. However, this might not be the best choice for paging through large query results because, although the DataAdapter fills the target DataTable or DataSet with only the requested records, the resources to return the entire query are still used. So, although it works in your case, resource usage still might be very large.

Comment: The problem seems to happen when the results are being stored in the memory, not from SQL, so perhaps it's not the most optimal choice but it works. I'll go this route and once I fully understand c# I'll come back and try to refactor or find a new, more optimal way